# Creating an array of records from search result

Tags: javascript

I have been helping a friend improve on his code to create a record with the search result but instead of it creating an array of records it simply returns the last result. How do I get an array of records created? i.e. searching for in will create a record with:

title: Inheritance: Inheritance Cycle, Book 4
score: 2

title: The Sense of an Ending
score: 1

```
books = [
  {
    title: "Inheritance: Inheritance Cycle, Book 4",
    author: "Christopher Paolini",
  },
  {
    title: "The Sense of an Ending",
    author: "Julian Barnes"
  },
  {
    title: "Snuff Discworld Novel 39",
    author: "Sir Terry Pratchett",
  }
]
search = prompt("Title?");

function count(books, pattern) {
  var result = [];
  var record = {};
  for (i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
    var index = -1;
    result[i] = 0;
    do {
      index = books[i].title.toLowerCase().indexOf(pattern.toLowerCase(), index + 1);
      if (index >= 0) {
        result[i] = result[i] + 1;
        record.title = books[i].title;
        record.score = result[i];
      }
    } while (index >= 0)
  }
  return record.title + " " + record.score;
}
alert(count(books, search));
```

Comment: Please indent your code. Few here will be willing to try understand it if it is unreadable. I've done it for you this time.  And welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1):

You should return the `result` array, construct the `record` inside the loop with an initial score of 0, increment the score (and not the result) when a match is found in the inner loop, and insert the `record` to the `result` array only if the score is not zero:

```
function count(books, pattern) {
   var result = [];
   for (i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
     var record = {title: books[i].title, score: 0};
     var index = -1;
     do {
       index = books[i].title.toLowerCase().indexOf(pattern.toLowerCase(), index + 1);
       if (index >= 0) {
         record.score = record.score + 1
       }
    } while (index >= 0)
    if (record.score > 0) {
       result.push(record);
    }    
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/Hk7mU/

```
books = [
   {
     title: "Inheritance: Inheritance Cycle, Book 4",
     author: "Christopher Paolini",
   },
   {
     title: "The Sense of an Ending",
     author: "Julian Barnes"
   },
   {
     title: "Snuff Discworld Novel 39",
     author: "Sir Terry Pratchett",
   }
 ]



 function count(books, pattern) {
   var results = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
     var index   = -1;
     // create a record with zero score
     var record  = {title: books[i].title, score: 0};
     do {
       index = books[i].title.toLowerCase().indexOf(pattern.toLowerCase(), index + 1);
       if (index >= 0) {
         // increase score
         record.score++;
       }
     } while (index >= 0)

     // only add to results if score is greater than zero
     if(record.score > 0) {
       results.push(record);
     }
   }
   // return all results
   // an array containing records
   return results;
 }

  search = prompt("Title?");
  var searchResults = count(books, search);
  // loop through result and alert
  for(var i=0;i<searchResults.length;i++) {
    alert("Title: " + searchResults[i].title + " Score:" + searchResults[i].score);
  }
```